# Can't set shortcut by operator & in qt designer

Tags: qt, shortcut, qlabel

With `qt` designer, I want to set shortcut in `text` `label`.

[image]

As shown above, when I change *text* property to `&Cell`, shortcut with underline do not appear.

Thank you for your attention and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt creator in the form designer, select `Edit Buddies` button from the top of the form. then drag specified `QLabel` to the Control you want focus on it with `QLabel` shortcut.

Finally change your form to `Edit Widget` mode!

Then you can change your `QLabel` text with "&Cell".

Comment: Sorry ! when I select `Edit Buddies`, the `Widget Box` is locked, so can't drag `QLabel` to the Control.

Comment: @BobZhang correct it will be lock, but if you drag your label to another control, then you will see an arrow!!! try this again